# Webpack 2: vendor, common and specific bundles

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, chunks, code-splitting

With the `CommonsChunkPlugin` I currently have my code split up into:

```
vendors.js
common.js
page-1.js
page-2-authenticated.js
page-3-authenticated.js
```

So on `page-1.html` I load the following scripts:

```
<script src="vendors.js" />
<script src="common.js" />
<script src="page-1.js" />
```

It works fine and all the shared code in `page-1.js`, `page-2-authenticated.js` and `page-3-authenticated.js` are bundled into `common.js`.

As you can see, my application requires a user to be logged in for `page-2-authenticated.html` and `page-3-authenticated.html`. However, shared code in `page-2-authenticated.js` and `page-3-authenticated.js` is also bundled into `common.js`. **But I don't want to bother users who are not logged in, with code that is only used when you are logged in.**

So for `page-2-authenticated.html` **I would like to have**:

```
<script src="vendors.js" />
<script src="common.js" />
<script src="common-authenticated.js" /> // Shared code for authenticated users
<script src="page-2-authenticated.js" />
```

However, when I export a test variable in `common-authenticated.js` and import these into `page-2-authenticated.js` and `page-3-authenticated.js`, this shared code is still bundled into `common.js`. And `common-authenticated.js` is empty (just some `webpackJsonp([12],[],[85]);`).

I have the following webpack 2 config:

```
entry: {
  vendors: ['react'],
  common: 'index.js',
  'common-authenticated': 'common-authenticated.js',
  'page-1': 'page-1.js',
  'page-2-authenticated': 'page-2-authenticated.js',
  'page-3-authenticated': 'page-3-authenticated.js'
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    // The order of this array matters
    names: ['common', 'vendors'],
    minChunks: 2
  })
]
```

**Question:** How do I bundle specific code into `common-authenticated.js`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the following configuration:

```
entry: {
  // Same as in topic start
},

plugins: [
  /*
   * Check the files used for pages on which you need to be logged in
   * and bundle the shared code of these files in a chunk named
   * 'common-authenticated' (its output will be in 'common-authenticated.js')
   */
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common-authenticated',
    chunks: [
      'page-2-authenticated',
      'page-3-authenticated'
    ],
    minChunks: 2
  }),

  /*
   * Now check for shared code in the bundle defined above plus the files for
   * pages on which you do not need to be logged in. Bundle this shared code into
   * 'common.js'
   */
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    chunks: [
      'common-authenticated', // Name of the chunk defined above
      'page-1'
    ],
    minChunks: 2
  }),

  /*
   * I don't really now how this works. But it works :).
   * It generates the 'vendors.js'
   */
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendors',
    chunks: ['common', 'vendors'],
    minChunks: 2
  })
]
```

It gives me exactly what I want. The loading of scripts in `page-1.html` remains unchanged (I don't need `common-authenticated.js` there). And `page-2-authenticated.html` now has:

```
<script src="vendors.js" />
<script src="common.js" />
<script src="common-authenticated.js" /> // Shared code for authenticated users
<script src="page-2-authenticated.js" />
```